# How can I use JavaScript or jQuery to change the background color of the `Save` and `Cancel` buttons in a SharePoint 2013 edit form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

How can I use JavaScript or jQuery to change the background color of the `Save` and `Cancel` buttons in a SharePoint 2013 edit form?

Answer (score 2):

You can select the required element by value using jQuery

```
var submitButton = $("input[value='Submit']"); //use value='Cancel' for cancel button
```

Add CSS properties using jQuery [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method

```
submitButton.css("background-color", "green")
```

Make sure to add reference to the jQuery library file before performing the above operations.